# Omitted variables problem

Tags: regression, econometrics, endogeneity, omitted-variable-bias

I'm studying the omitted variables problem.

My model is:

$E[y|x_1,x_2,...,x_k,q]=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+...+\beta_k x_k + \gamma q$

[image]

From the first equation, I write the population model as

$y= \beta_0+\beta_1x_1+...+\beta_k x_k + \gamma q + \nu$

where, $\nu$ is the error, and I assumed $E[\nu |x_1,...,x_k,q]=0$

One way to handle this unobservability is to put $q$ in the error term. Without any loss of generality, I assume $E[q]=0$. By doing this, the population model reads as

$y= \beta_0+\beta_1x_1+...+\beta_k x_k + u$

where $u \equiv \gamma q + \nu$, and $E[u]=0$

If $q$ is correlated with one of the regressors, the endogeneity problem arises.

Then, the book says

[image]
[image]
where equation $(4.19)$ : $y= \beta_0+\beta_1x_1+...+\beta_k x_k + \gamma q + \nu$

How can I run a linear projection (that I guess is the same of a linear regression) on $q$, if $q$ is unobserved?

The book's reference is : Wooldridge - econometric analysis of cross section and panel data, last edition (pages 65-66).

Comment: My guess is that the proposed linear projection is hypothetical, to demonstrate the nature of the bias if you actually knew $q$ and its associations with the included predictors. Please add more information from the book, or a direct reference to the book (with a web link, if possible), if that's not how the matter is pursued later in the text.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. References added. The book denotes $q$ an unobservable. I think that you are right, otherwise it would impossible to run that linear projection

Comment: I don't think $q$ is "unobserved", it just gets "omitted".  You should include more excerpts after (4.23) to see what the author tries to convey.

Comment: I'm going to add more details right now. $q$ is omitted because not observed. Otherwise, if observed, why don't add it in the model?

Comment: @JohnM. Not every model has to include every single variable you observed. This passage is about the consequences of omitting variables from a regression, so asking "why would we omit a variable?" is beside the point. There are many reasons you would omit a variable, even if you measured it: you don't want to overfit your model, you don't want to include a bad control, you fear your variable has too much measurement error, you want to see what the estimates look like without adjusting for it, etc. This passage is about statistical facts, not strategies for data analysis.

Comment: @Noah that is clear. I was just following the the discussion of the book, where omitting $q$ gave inconsistent estimates for the $\beta_s$ because $q$ was correlated with other regressors. Maybe as you and others pointed out, it is just that $q$ is "omitted" and not unobserved, otherwise I could not regress $q$ on the other regressors. Just a remark, if you can, why the book talks about linear projection, and not a simple linear regression? Are they the same?

Comment: @JohnM. In my opinion, "linear projection" of the response variable vector $y$ onto the space spanned by columns of $X$ is a geometric way of reflecting the nature of "linear regression".  So loosely speaking, yes, they are the same.  It is not very standard though, using "linear projection" with the explicit model $q = \delta_0 + \delta_1 x_1 + \cdots + \delta_Kx_K + r$ (the thing I feel uncomfortable is the error term $r$, when the term "linear projection" is used, "$r$" is usually suppressed because that's what "projection" really means).

Comment: (continued) However, the point made by the author is still unambiguous because he placed down an explicit regression model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 4.1 of the Wooldridge text describes what's being considered:

> The correlation of explanatory variables with unobservables is often due to *self-selection*: if agents choose the value of [independent variable] $x_j$, this might depend on factors ($q$) that are unobservable to the analyst. A good example is omitted ability in a wage equation, where an individual’s years of schooling are likely to be correlated with unobserved ability. We discuss the omitted variables problem in detail in Section 4.3.

In that context, the "linear projection" in Equation 4.23 (from Section 4.3) is a *hypothetical* projection. (It might only be considered a linear "regression" if you had actual values to work with.) If you somehow knew how $q$ is associated with the $x_j$, then you could perform the substitutions shown to come up with the critical result: if $q$ is uncorrelated with $x_j$, then in linear regression it introduces no bias into the estimate of the corresponding $\beta_j$; if $q$ is correlated with $x_K$ then (Equation 4.24):

$$\text{plim  } \hat\beta_K = \beta_K + \gamma \left[\text{Cov}(x_K,q)/\text{Var}(x_K) \right] $$

where $\text{plim  } \hat\beta_K$ is the limit in probability of the coefficient estimate in the model omitting $q$, and $\beta_K$ is the true coefficient. In practice, if you can make reasonable assumptions about that correlation, it allows you to gauge the nature of the bias.

Comment: Clear! The very last point, why the book talks about linear projection, and not a simple linear regression? Are they the same?

Comment: @JohnM. I think that the distinction is between a "linear projection" of a random variable upon other random variables and the _estimate_ of that projection that would be accomplished by a linear regression. If you don't have the values of $q$ you can at least imagine the "projection" even if you have no data for the "regression."